# Strct standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, html

I have this code

```
$maxSize="44400000";
$allowedExts = array("jpg","jpeg","docx","png","JPG");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
```

and giving me error shown below.

The Main problem is with the above line.

> Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Comment: just reassign the explosion first, then use end

Answer (score 1):

You have to create one more variable:

```
$maxSize="44400000";
$allowedExts = array("jpg","jpeg","docx","png","JPG");
$extension = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$final_ext = end($extension);
```

But it's better to use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to do this.

```
$path = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

As end function only accepts argument that must be passed by reference
you should do this :

```
$maxSize="44400000";
$allowedExts = array("jpg","jpeg","docx","png","JPG");
$explode = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($explode);
```

read more 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php